# went from 940 observations to 883,600

Tags: r, dataframe

Title is whole issue I don't know how I went from 940 observations in HourlyActivity and DailyActivity to 883,600 observations in AllActivity.

trying to change minutes into hours so that the graphs looks better as the minutes range from 0-5,000 so even with a width = 50 the bar graphs look zoomed out.

```
SedentaryHour <- DailyActivity$SedentaryMinutes/60
LightlyActiveHour <- DailyActivity$LightlyActiveMinutes/60
FairlyActiveHour <- DailyActivity$FairlyActiveMinutes/60
VeryActiveHour <- DailyActivity$VeryActiveMinutes/60
```

created data frame for these values (and then viewed it to make sure it transferred correctly and it does)

```
HourlyActivity <- data.frame(SedentaryHour, LightlyActiveHour, FairlyActiveHour, VeryActiveHour)

View(HourlyActivity)
```

merging Id column from DailyActivity into HourlyActivity.

```
AllActivity <- merge(HourlyActivity, DailyActivity[c("Id")], all.HourlyActivity=TRUE)
```

and now AllActivity has 883,600 obs., but I only want it to have 940 just like the other 2 and I don't know where the extra data has came from.

#I tried to see if there are Duplicates, but it wants a specific column and just errors.

```
AllActivity <- AllActivity[duplicated(AllActivity$SedentaryHour)]
```

This errors: Error in `[.data.frame`(AllActivity, duplicated(AllActivity$SedentaryHour)) :
undefined columns selected

extra info: There are duplicate IDs as each Id logged multiple dates for information, but each Id is ~30 obs in HourlyActivity and DailyActivity, but in AllActivity each Id jumps to 2000+ Obs.

Any help would be awesome and I am new so I hope this isn't really obvious.

Thank you so much!

Comment: 940*940 = 883600, so your merge is matching every row of HourlyActivity to every row of DailyActivity. This bit of your `merge` line - `all.HourlyActivity=TRUE` should be `all.x=TRUE`, and you should probably specify a `by="Id"` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

940*940 = 883600, so your merge is matching every row of `HourlyActivity` to every row of `DailyActivity`.

Looking at your pasted code, the `HourlyActivity` file doesn't have a "Id" column, which will result in a cartesian join and the massive result. E.g., on a small example with two 3 row data.frames, you get 9 in the output:

```
HourlyActivity <- data.frame(val=2:4)
DailyActivity <- data.frame(Id = 1:3, val=3:5)
merge(HourlyActivity, DailyActivity[c("Id")])

#  val Id
#1   2  1
#2   3  1
#3   4  1
#4   2  2
#5   3  2
#6   4  2
#7   2  3
#8   3  3
#9   4  3
```